# Sorted Bar Chart

Tags: d3.js, label, bar-chart

I like the d3 [sortable bar chart example](http://bl.ocks.org/3885705):

[image]

Unfortunately, it doesn't appear to work correctly in v2 (the example uses v3). At first, I thought it was me, so wrote a [new example](https://gist.github.com/4254171) from scratch. Alas, it wasn't! In v2 the x axis labels don't transition with the bars; in v3 both labels and bars transition together.

Can anyone suggest a workaround for v2?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So yes, the obvious answer is to use v3. However, v3 causes other parts of my code to fail, and I'd like to make an informed choice about whether to spend the time either debugging or coding the desired behaviour using v2.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think there are two solutions to this problem. As Robert Harvey pointed out, you could use v3. The main difference that I can see so far is that `d3.tsv` (and possibly the other read data methods) take an additional parameter: this was what was causing the other parts of my code to fail. So, even though v3 isn't the latest release, this is my preferred solution.

The second solution is to transition the axis labels explicitly. This would take more code and as v3 is (hopefully!) on the horizon, might only be necessary if you really can't wait and absolutely must use v2.